# How to use Created (or CreatedAtAction / CreatedAtRoute) in an asp net core api

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I'd like to inform consumers of my api about the location of the newly created object. I know there is `Created()` `CreatedAtRoute()` and `CreatedAtAction()` but I am unsure how to use it.

Here is what I've tried:

I have a **Get** resource to which I would like to point. It takes an ID as input:

```
    [HttpGet("/${id}", Name = "GetProduct")]
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(Produkt), 200)]
    public IActionResult Get([FromRoute] int id)
    {
       // some code...
        return Ok(...);
    }
```

When a product gets created via my **POST** route, I would like to point to this Resource via the Location header:

**Attempt 1**

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(Produkt), 200)]
    public IActionResult CreateNewProduct([FromBody] ProduktDtoForCreate productFromBody)
    {
        //...
        return CreatedAtRoute("GetProduct", new { id = productToCreate.Id }, productToCreate);
    }
```

This returns a **Location Header** of: **http://localhost:5000/$15003**

**Attempt 2**

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(Produkt), 200)]
    public IActionResult CreateNewProduct([FromBody] ProduktDtoForCreate productFromBody)
    {
        //...
        return Created(new Uri($"{Request.Path}/{productToCreate.Id}", UriKind.Relative), productToCreate);
    }
```

This one works and returns **/api/v1.0/produkte/16004** but it seems like using the current request to point to the new location should not be needed. Also I am not sure if this is good practice?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your route for the Get method, take both the leading / and the $ out (i.e. it should just be "{id}"). Having the leading / in there means that the route will be relative to the base of the application; taking it out makes the route for the method relative to the controller's base path instead. The $ is being treated as a literal character in the route, hence why it was appearing in the Location header in Attempt 1. Once you've made the changes, you should find that your CreatedAtRoute call works as you would expect.

Comment: I would also add, that your ProducesResponseType annotation for the CreateNewProduct method should specify a 201 return code, and not 200.

Comment: Thank you Graham! I was so focused on the CreatedAt Method that I made a silly mistake in my Get method :) Have a great 2018

Answer (score 42):

`CreatedAtAction` gives the best output in my opinion. The following controller code will do what you need:

```
[Route("api/products")]
[ApiController]
public class ProductsController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IProductRepository productRepository;

    public ProductsController(IProductRepository productRepository)
    {
        this.productRepository = productRepository;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("")]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status201Created)]
    public ActionResult<Product> CreateProduct(ProductCreateDto product)
    {
        if (product is null)
            return BadRequest(new ArgumentNullException());

        var entity = productRepository.CreateProduct(product);

        return CreatedAtAction(nameof(GetProduct), new { id = entity.ID }, entity);
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("{id}")]
    public ActionResult<Product> GetProduct(int id)
    {
        return productRepository.GetProduct(id);
    }
}
```

Issuing the following request:

```
POST http://localhost:5000/api/products HTTP/1.1 
Host: localhost:5000
Connection: keep-alive 
Content-Length: 25 
Content-Type: application/json

{ "name": "ACME Widget" }
```

Will yield the following response:

```
HTTP/1.1 201 Created
Date: Mon, 12 Oct 2020 09:50:00 GMT
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Server: Kestrel
Content-Length: 29
Location: http://localhost:5000/api/products/1

{"id":1,"name":"ACME Widget"}
```

Comment: isn't that an uneccessary 2nd call to the same entity? Any way to avoid that and returning Created directly from POST controller? In my case I have no need for a /{id} to retrieve individual

Comment: The POST includes the entity you want to create in the body, returns status code 201 and includes the newly created entity in the body of the response. It isn't a second call. There is an argument to say that the body response is redundant since you just submitted it - however as in the example above, the action of creating adds extra detail to the entity (ID in this case, but might also include date, created by etc) so this is useful. This also matches the behaviour described here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/201

Comment: What if the API does not support GET for the resource by ID, what's the CreatedAtAction supposed to link to then?

Comment: @user3625699 Just return Created() then

Answer (score 3):

Quoting [RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.3.2):

> The 201 (Created) status code indicates that the request has been
> fulfilled and has resulted in one or more new resources being created.
> The primary resource created by the request is identified by either a
> Location header field in the response or, if no Location field is
> received, by the effective request URI.

What identifies the resource depends on the context. In my interpretation, if the resource created resides at `<request_uri>/<id>`, the identifier can be just `<id>`.